# Eclipse OSGi Framwork launcher available bundles

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bundle, equinox

What is the proper way of adding bundles to the bundles screen in the OSGi Framework launcher?
I've been adding them in the plug-ins folder inside eclipse. It worked for some bundles but not all of them.

Is there any other way of adding bundles?

Also, is there any way to find out why a bundle doesn't show up in that screen?

Comment: Are you using a `Target Platform` or just your installed Eclipse?

Comment: I just installed eclipse. Thanks for the tip about target platform. I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the OSGi Framework run configuration that comes standard with the eClipse Plugin development environment and not the one that comes with bndtools.

In that case, the bundles shown in the launcher depend on the definition of the Target platform. This platform is a set of bundles that are added to your plug-in projects for the run configuration. The default definition is the eClipse runtime.

You can define your own target platform via New...Target Definition option in the Plugin development view. In this target definition you can add some directories, features or eClipse plugins that you want to include, which allows you to add your own directory with bundles. Afterwards you can define this target as the target definition to use for the workspace by pressing the link "Set as target platform" in the Target definition edit window.